# jqPlot mouseOver on pie chart

Tags: javascript, hover, jqplot

I am using jqplot version 1.0.8r1250 and I can't figure out how to get the mouseOver event to work on the pie chart slice. The normal seriesColors work fine though.

Here is my code:

```
$.jqplot('pieChart', [pieChartData],
{
   seriesColors: [color1, color2, color3, color4],
    grid: {
             background:'#FFFFFF',
             borderWidth:0,
             shadow:0
           },

     seriesDefaults: {
                        renderer: $.jqplot.PieRenderer,
                        rendererOptions: {
                                           highlightMouseOver: true,
                                           highlightMouseDown: false,
                                           highlightColor:  [hoverColor1, 
                                                             hoverColor2,
                                                              hoverColor3,
                                                             hoverColor4],
                                                },
                                            },
                             legend: {
                                        show: true, 
                                        location: 'e'
                                    },

                        });
```

Answer (score 2):

This should help you:

```
//On mouseover
    $('.jqplot-target').bind('jqplotDataHighlight', function(evt, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
          //place your logic here
    });

//On mouseout    
    $('.jqplot-target').bind('jqplotDataUnhighlight', function(evt, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data){
         //place your logic here
    });
```